# TYPO3 v9.5.0 - Bootstrap Package url error message

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I have a TYPO3 9.5.0LTS and use the bootstrap package theme. It seems to be all working ... I defined the site configuration and then I get nice looking urls ... but quite often I get such error messages:

Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #1436717266: Invalid header value for header "Expire"". The value must be a string or an array of strings. | InvalidArgumentException thrown in file /is/www/typo3_src-9.5.0/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/Message.php in line 208. Requested URL: domain/content-examples/media/audio

What causes this and how to prevent this?

Edit: Might be this part in TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Controller\TypoScriptFrontendController::getHttpHeadersForTemporaryContent() on line 4244:

```
/**
 * Returns HTTP headers for temporary content.
 * These headers prevent search engines from caching temporary content and asks them to revisit this page again.
 * Please ensure to also send a 503 HTTP Status code with these headers.
 */
protected function getHttpHeadersForTemporaryContent(): array
{
    return [
        'Retry-after' => '3600',
        'Pragma' => 'no-cache',
        'Cache-control' => 'no-cache',
        'Expire' => 0,
    ];
}
```

... so I change it to 'Expires' => 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://forge.typo3.org/issues/86651#change-388813

It seems there's a typo in "Expire" header, should be "Expires".
Try to change it in:
TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Controller\TypoScriptFrontendController::getHttpHeadersForTemporaryContent() 
while they're fixing this problem

**UPD**

TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Controller\TypoScriptFrontendController, line 4244

> 'Expire' => 0,

change to

> 'Expires' => '0',

https://forge.typo3.org/issues/86658

And correct header name should be 'Expires' afaik:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expires

Comment: ... I'm not sure where to exactly change it ... but good to see it already has been reported

Comment: .. I might found it ... the only part where it says 'Expire' => 0 ... and maybe it hast to be 'Expires' => 0

Comment: ... nope ... now I'm still getting 
'Oops, an error occurred!
Invalid header value for header "Expires"". The value must be a string or an array of strings.'

Comment: They've just made string from int, hope it will be helpful: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/86658

Answer (score 0):

I think to change the file:

typo3_src-9.5.0/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/Controller/TypoScriptFrontendController.php

on line 4244 from

'Expire' => 0,

to

'Expire' => '0',

helps. The issue is reported https://forge.typo3.org/issues/86658 and will be changed with the next update, I am sure.